# Relation API usage on Foreign key fields

Tags: google-app-maker

I have  code as below

```
var ds = widget.datasource;
ds.item.InvoiceID_fk = 10;
ds.saveChanges();
```

InvoiceID_fk is a foreign key field.

It says "Foreign key usage is deprecated. Please Relation API instead."
How do we use Relation API for above code?

Thank you

Comment: Your relation needs to be set equal to the related record instead of the related record key. So for example ds.item.InvoiceID_fk = app.datasources.YourRelatedDatasource.item; That should fix this.

Comment: Hi @MarkusMalessa

But we are still using InvoiceID_fk
ds.item.InvoiceID_fk

Is that correct?

Comment: If InvoiceID_fk is your relation then yes. The example I tried was setting a manager to an employee by doing widget.datasource.item.Managers = app.datasources.Managers.item; and this worked in my situation. Of course normally I would have a field in the Employee Create form that would set the Manager relation instead, but this is a similar concept, it just selects the currently selected record in Managers as the relation. However, do keep in mind that your other datasource needs to be loaded in the client also. If its not loaded then this will not work.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa - Is this the Relation API which google recommends? I thought it was external library which need refereed to the project?

Comment: I believe when the AM documentation references the Relation API, it really just refers to the coding needed to set or change your relations. The program essentially no longer allows for foreign key changes like some people were using before.